# How to set the text of a back button on a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the title of the “back” button on a Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar)

**The Situation:**
I have a UIViewController that is governed by a navigation controller. I am able to set the *title* of the navigation bar covering the UIViewController by simply calling `self.title = @"title"`. But, I want to be able to set the **back button text** of the navigation bar, too (for different languages n' such..)

**The Problem:**
I don't know how to set the back button's text.

**The Question:**
How do I set the back button of the UINavigation bar (programmatically not in IB)?

Comment: Good question. There may not be a documented way to do this (I honestly don't know), but I'd be surprised if changing it to anything that isn't the title of the previous item or the word "Back" wasn't against the HIG. And if it is against the HIG, there's a good chance this customization could lead to an app rejection. /2cents.

Comment: Suggest setting your "accept" to Boon's answer, which is correct.  Matt's answer is not a good solution (sorry, Matt! :)

Comment: Changing the back label is not against the HIG, it just has to make sense.

Answer (score 148):

The setTitle way - though may seem to work, is incorrect.  If you pay attention closely, you will notice that the navigation item changes to the new title while the new view is animated into view via pushViewController.  The fact that you have to restore your title in viewWillAppear is kludgy, which further suggests its hack nature.

The correct way is to do the following before your pushViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithTitle: @"Back Button Text" 
                                style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target: nil action: nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
[backButton release];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, will not work in a `prepareForSegue:sender:` callback. I am not sure what the accepted solution is for storyboards.

Comment: I got this to work just fine in a prepareForSegue:sender: callback. Just get rid of [backButton release]; if you are using ARC.

Comment: One thing is worth emphasizing here: you set the backbutton on the current view controller, and you will see it in the next viewcontroller... in case it helps anyone.. it helped me.

Comment: Question: can't you just do `[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"TEST"];`? This way you don't have to worry about setting up the target/action again (or the style).

Comment: @KieranSenior not working on iOS7

Comment: @artworkadシ Must be a specific case then, mine worked a treat.

Comment: Because Back button is related to the previous ViewController you need to apply these code in that controller in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Checked on iOS 8 and it didn't work. Changing the previous viewcontroller title was the only thing that did

Comment: Use UIBarButtonItemStylePlain when minimum deployment target is iOS7 or later. UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered is deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

The best and easiest way according to apple documentation to set the view controller's title to what the back should say is this -

**Example:**

If `viewController1` is under `viewController2`  (and the `back button` on `viewController2` is going to `viewController1`)

```
viewController1.title = @"something awesome";
```

the `back button` on `viewController2` will show **"something awesome"**

Comment: If you add a title to the view controllers in the navigation stack, that title will appear as the back button's title. "Back" is the default text. You don't need to remove this title after it's been set either. Therefore this is the correct answer.