# screen naviagation iphone, xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

i'm having 3 screens
set title to screen1 using

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.navigationItem.title =@"Products";
}`

when navigation to next screen (screen2) second screen having the title "Categories"
but there is a button on the top name "Products" to Screen1

i want to change the button name as "Back"

Please tell me how?

tried`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem .title = @"Back";`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the text of a back button on a UINavigationBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197698/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-back-button-on-a-uinavigationbar)

Answer (score 0):

See these two:

[How to set the text of a back button on a UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197698/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-back-button-on-a-uinavigationbar)

[How do I change the title of the "back" button on a Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar)

Solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem *item=self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=item;
    [item release];

Put this code in your first scree viewDidLoad method as it is It really works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like the follows to set the text of the back bar button to something other than what the previous view was named:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
barButton.title = @"Your Custom Title";

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

You CANNOT do the following:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

This sets the previous view on the stack to "Your Title" and not was it was before.