# How do I add back button to UINavigationBar programmatically?

Tags: ios, button, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController and when I push one of my views, I have a UINavigationBar on top that I made an ivar for and connected it. Now what I need is that button that is like half square and half arrow on the left of the bar. How would I do this programmatically? All I need it to do is say back and do my back action when it is clicked. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197698/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-back-button-on-a-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a UINaviationController, then each view controller that you push onto it does not need it's own UINavigationBar object set up in the nib or in code.  You get it and a back button 'for free' when you push a view controller onto a navigation controller's stack.

So remove the UINavigationBar from your pushed view controller.  It could actually be blocking the navigation controller's navigation bar.

If you're using a nib to set up your view controller, you can add a 'simulated element' so that you have a fake navigation bar in the nib to help lay out your UI elements.

EDIT: in Xcode 4, they're now called 'Simulated Metrics'.  Set the 'Top Bar' to simulate a navigation bar in your nib.

[image]