# Get a BackButton on UINavigationBar saying 'Back' using localizations defined by iOS

Tags: ios, localization, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationBar` with two different screens. 
On both screens the NavigationBar has the same title.
So the BackButton should have just `Back` as text instead of the NavigationBar's title.

If I set the parents ViewController title to `nil` I have a backButton with the text `Back`, which gets localized automatically by iOS.

I know I can set the text to back as described in this question: [How to set the text of a back button on a UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197698/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-back-button-on-a-uinavigationbar)
However, then the `Back` is hardcoded and wont get translated by iOS automatically.

I don't want to maintain the localizations by myself in the `Localizable.strings` but rather use the predefined values from iOS.

I would like to always have a title on my NavigationBar and a backButton which says `Back` and gets localized automatically using the by iOS defined values.

Does somebody know if and how such an behavior could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot force that behavior. One way of getting around it would be by adding the title to the navigation bar with a, say, UITextView:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:myUITextView]
```

Comment: It would solve your issue. And doing it the way I describe is not that much of a hassle. I would make a factory method for the view you want to use for setting the titles, and then you can set the title in one line of code in your viewcontrollers. Something like [self.navigationItem setTitleView:[ViewFactory navTitleView:@"MyTitle"]]