# Programmatically edit title of controller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Previously, I was trying to go to another controller using the following code but failed

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RowDetail *rd = [[RowDetail alloc]initWithNibName:@"RowDetail" bundle:nil];
    if ([[allRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is Equal:@"One"]) 
    {
        [rd setTitle:[allRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.navigationalController pushViewController:rd animated:NO];
}
```

I am using a storyboard so I found the other code worked for me but I could not set the title for the controller I was pushing.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
    RowDetail *rd = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RowDetail"];
    if ([[allRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is Equal:@"One"]) 
    {
        [rd setTitle:[allRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.navigationalController pushViewController:rd animated:NO];
}
```

It worked and showed the RowDetail controller but I could not edit the title. Any idea how can this be done?

EDIT:
RowDetail.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LecturerDetail : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *rowNavBar;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lecDetailTitle;
@end
```

For the RowDetail, I tried using IBOutlet for the navigation bar but failed. I am still trying ways to let the title to show.

Comment: please see my update it's easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RowDetailViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *rowDetailTitle;
//synthesize in .m file too
```

then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
    RowDetail *rd = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RowDetail"];
    rd.rowDetailTitle = @"yourTitle";
    [self.navigationalController pushViewController:rd animated:NO];
}
```

then in view did load of RowDetailViewController.m

```
self.navigationItem.title = rowDetailTitle;
```

hope it help, please give a feedback, thanks.

UPDATE: or just simply do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
    RowDetail *rd = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RowDetail"];
    rd.navigationItem.title = @"yourTitle";
    [self.navigationalController pushViewController:rd animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I tried both method but it still doesn't show the title screen

Comment: can I see your RowDetailViewController.h ?

Comment: rowNavBar.title = self.navigationItem.title; in viewdidload of RowDetailViewController.m

Comment: rowNavBar.topItem.title = self.navigationalItem.title;

Comment: I misreading your .h file , so for conclusion UINavigationBar use navBar.topItem.title = @"title"; but if UINavigationItem do as I said :)

Comment: Another question, if I want to do the same method for button instead of navigational title, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: you mean something like this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197698/how-to-set-the-text-of-a-back-button-on-a-uinavigationbar>

Comment: Nope, I mean for a rounded rect button. There is a rounded rect button in the RowDetailViewController and I want to edit it in the previous controller.

Comment: For your second question, after I tried, unfortunately it failed :(, why don't you edit your button in RowDetailViewController.m? sorry dude.

Comment: I'll need to use my array in the previous controller to vary the output in RowDetailViewController that's why. I will try figure.

Comment: so the only solution that I can think is to send value from previous controller to RowDetailViewController look at my first answer, you have to do like that then edit you roundrecBtn according to the value you have sent in viewdidload