# Changing text on automatically created button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've been a lurker for some time on Stackoverflow, and here is my first iOS post.

I am implementing a UINavigationController programmatically and am using it for the default back buttons. The text that is on the back button is defaulted to the name of the title in the previous navigation bar's view, due to the stack.

I wish to change the text on the back button (left bar button) without creating a new UIBarButtonItem, so that I can avoid using a selector and instead use the stack that I have been using. I also wish to avoid creating a new button object, since there is one already inside the NavController.

Example: NavViewA titled A, advances to NavViewB titled B. The left bar button in NavViewB now says 'A', however, I wish it to say "Turtles".

1. How would I go about doing this?
2. If I do end up creating a new UIButtonItem and just using that with a selector that pops, will the default button in the NavController deallocate itself, or will it be taking up memory?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291832/641062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this in `viewDidLoad` of your `NavViewControllerA`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Turtles" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

It'll still do the pop for you.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didn't know that you could set an action to nil.
Do you know if allocating this chunk is bad(allocating two of the same thing), or does it know that you are creating it manually, so it won't create the default one.