# Problem with button in navigationItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

i create a tableViewController in this way:

```
myTableViewController *tableController = [[[myTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myTableViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

// Setto il pulsante per tornare indietro
UIBarButtonItem *tempButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
tempButton.title = @"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = tempButton;
[tempButton release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:NO];
```

then in the tableviewcontroller, making self.navigationItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = ... it does'nt happen anything, i've seen that the backbutton is = null.

How can i do? i've tried cutting off the creation of button in first code but it's the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different init method for UIBarButtonItem:

```
                    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                               target:nil 
                                               action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set the action for back button.

1. Initialization button action when an object is created

> UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
>   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
>                                                          initWithTitle:@"Back"
>                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
>                                                          target:nil 
>                                                          action:nil];

1. Directly add target after allocating object for button

> [backButton addTarget:nil
>   action:nil];