# Change title of BarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I change this title on button?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to read these messages first. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D+change+back+button+title

Comment: I have got action on first page
TimetableViewNew *winframe=[[[TimetableViewNew alloc]init]autorelease];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:winframe animated:YES];

after this I have this screen. This button I can't edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar

Comment: how I can do this button with triangle http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0126/7e/22351c547c438c7c0e9f288b0edea57e.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If this is coming from a Navigation controller, setting the title of the parent VC will set the title of the button to that string value.

Comment: I doing this
 UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Назад" 
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(OnClick_btnBack:)];
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;

I need this style of button http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0126/7e/22351c547c438c7c0e9f288b0edea57e.jpg

Comment: Yes, but what it the title attribute of the parent view controller?

Comment: In the view controller that pushes that view with the button, put this in the viewDidLoad event: self.title=@"Назад";

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK doesn't allow to change the title of the back button.

Instead, you can replace the back button with a custom back button:

```
+ (void)setBackButtonForViewController:(UIViewController *)vc target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
{
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"];

    [backButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    [backButton addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
    vc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [temporaryBarButtonItem release];    
}
```

You can grab the back_button.png image from http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/.

Comment: It can do with TTButton class with Three20 library, but for my experience add library to XCode and other it is to hard,

Comment: I believe the TTButton class also creates a custom back button. If you'll use my code the end result will be the same.