# Use Image for backBarButtonItem with NO TEXT

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm simply trying to set the backBarButtonItem for my navigation controller to this image

[image]

instead of the Apple default arrow button whose title is the same as the previous view controller's title. The closest I've gotten so far is the above image stretched horizontally with the title still appearing overlaid. To get that, I used this code in my AppDelegate.

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How can I get rid of the title (and prevent the button from being stretched)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set custom Image of BarbuttonItem like :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    UIImage* imageRight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_btn.png"];
    CGRect frameimgRight = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 30);

    RightBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgRight];
    [RightBtn setBackgroundImage:imageRight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [RightBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionhomeBtn)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:RightBtn];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnRight;

  [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Look like:-

[image]

Hope its halp's you

Answer (score 2):

When you use appearance, you are setting the background image of the back bar button items of your app.  The fact that they have a background image has nothing to do with whether or not there is a title displayed on them.  To use a custom bar button item instead of the default back item, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar).

In your case, you may want to not use appearance at all and instead create a bar button item as in the link above but use `-initWithImage:style:target:action:` instead of `-initWithTitle:style:target:action:`

Answer (score 0):

I know this method works, and should be called in ViewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:@selector(methodName)];
```

which then has to be assigned to the nav bar:

```
item.rightBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

and then pushed:

```
[self.navBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```