# change UIBarButtonItem back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change the navigation controller backBarButton,
with out create new function of back.
here is my code:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backt.clicked@2x~iphone.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 27, 0, 27)];
```

(width =27,hight=27);

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and here what i get:

[image]

how can i change the size and remove the title?

Comment: Resd this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar

Comment: thanx but its not work ether...

Comment: What code your tried, paste your code here.

Comment: i already posted it up top.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)createBackMenuButton {
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setFrame:BACK_BUTTON_FRAME];
    [backButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACK_BUTTON_DEFAULT_ICON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonHolder = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    return backButtonHolder;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self createBackMenuButton];
}
```

Comment: i want something more simple,i dont want to add new function for the back item,i want to use the default navigation controller back function.

Comment: popViewControllerAnimated:  this IS the default navigation controller back function :D

Comment: yeah i know :)
but im pretty sure that there is option to change the image only dont u thing?

Comment: That simple option is to change the backGround image of the button, just as you did; but if you want to change the image, and not the backGround image, you should do as I suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backt.clicked@2x~iphone.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 27, 0, 27)];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[button setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

**EDIT**

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backt.clicked@2x~iphone.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 27, 0, 27)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

Comment: i want something more simple,i dont want to add new function for the back item,i want to use the default navigation controller back function.
is that possible?

Comment: when the title is @"" like u wrote - the back button is disappear..
if i add @" " (with space) its getting to big..
and anyway the image size is not really set..

Comment: @Esty you should really resize your actual image if it is too big. ignore heavy assets

Comment: then how can i resize it??

Comment: @Esty you resize image as per navigation size using any image editor :)