# Pushed viewcontroller not taking on title of previous one for back button

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am having a weird issue with a pushed view controller not taking my previous view controller title and using it as the back button title.

Playing around with it to try to get it to work I got the below code working and the other not working.  The self.team.name is a little longer then back but it always defaults to "Back".  Any clue why one works and the other doesnt?

**Doesnt Work**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = self.team.name;
}
```

**Works**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"back";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the title of the "back" button on a Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar)

Comment: Ive seen that but I am asking why the code works the way it does.

Comment: This is new behavior in iOS 8. If the title of the back button would be too long, it simply says "Back".

Comment: Post that as the answer then, but I dont have iOS 8 installed?

Comment: Why do you set your title in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: This question is not already answered please dont close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 7 (I mistakenly said iOS 8 in my comment), if the title of the back button would be too long, iOS automatically show the button title as "Back".