# How can I change UIImagePickerController navigation bar font?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I need it to be Helvetica Neue Light. Here is how I create the controller

```
let picker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
picker.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

Comment: Did you try setting `picker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
picker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 21)!]
```

Also, a small problem with your code: `UIImagePickerController` derived from `UINavigationController`, and `picker.navigationController?` is always `nil` in your code above.

Comment: Do you know how to access the library back button through my code

Comment: I need to change it to just the back arrow

Comment: @ConnorB, as far as I know, there is no explicitly way to change bar button to a back button with the left arrow if that is what you are asking for. That back button is automatically added if you are using a navigation controller and push a new view controller to a navigation stack.

Comment: Well How can I change the back bar button title

Comment: If you are only wanting to change the title, this is how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar

Comment: You can change the back button by setting the picker delegate, which is also a UINavigationControllerDelegate. Then you can set the left bar button item when the navigation controller will show the UIImagePicker